# Reference request for Category Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory

Although this question has been asked before, I want to ask a kind of more specific/different request concerning category theory (perhaps a bit more precise). I have gone through Emily's Riehl book *''Category theory in context''* and I can say, I understand it in a very good level. However this a basic book in category theory, which is a huge area of research hence quite broad, that covers up the main theory that almost everyone needs to know in algebra nowadays. So I was wondering if there is a *"natural"* extension of that book going towards the knowledge you need, to deal with the advanced stuff popping out category theory, like algebraic geometry, categorical logic, homotopy theory, sheaf theory etc. In other words, a book that comprises the appropriate categorical language/knowledge to go through deeper theories and results in mathematics.

**DISCLAIMER:**

As I have been mentioned above, I do know the vastness of category theory and what I am asking is probably a little bit absurd, however there could probably be a textbook treating a second step in category theory, so that's why am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, category theory and its applications are vast, and a book going deeper in category theory will necessarily narrow the field it covers (otherwise, it is called the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage)).

Now depending on which field you want to go deeper in, there is some textbooks that are recognized as references. Here a non exhaustive list of those I'm thinking about:

- categorical logic (from a math perspective): *[Sheaves in geometry and logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0927-0)* by Mac Lane and Moerdijk and *[Sketches of an elephant](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/sketches-of-an-elephant-a-topos-theory-compendium-9780198534259?lang=en&cc=nl)* by Johnstone, and also most of Lawvere's papers,
- categorical logic (from a CS perspective): *[Categorical logic and type theory](https://www.elsevier.com/books/categorical-logic-and-type-theory/jacobs/978-0-444-50170-7)* by Jacobs,
- algebraic geometry: all SGAs are written with heavy category theory, *[Algebraic geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-3849-0)* by Hartshorne, and I should mention [Stack Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/),
- sheaf theory: *[Sheaves in geometry and logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0927-0)* by Maclane and Moerdijk and *[Categories and Sheaves](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-27950-4)* by Shapira and Kashiwara
- abelian categories and homological agebra: Grothendieck's Tohoku original paper *Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique* is very readable if you read french, and *[An Introduction to Homological Algebra](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/introduction-homological-algebra-1?format=PB&isbn=9780521559874#KBgF8FiPx3AUQgv7.97)* by Weibel seems to be quite a hit, and *[Categories and Sheaves](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-27950-4)* by Shapira and Kashiwara
- homotopy theory: *[Homotopical algebra](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0097438)* by Quillen started it all but is not that easy to read, *[Model categories](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-63-s/)* by Hovey might be an easier entry point, and Grothendieck's tapuscript *Pursuing stacks* is worth at least browsing,
- higher category theory: *[Higher Topos Theory](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8957.html)* by Lurie, *[Higher operads, higher categories](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/higher-operads-higher-categories?format=PB#VAEHdMT569ShWH2u.97)* by Leinster
- Also, try not to forget to take a look at *[Categories for the working mathematician](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4721-8)* by Mac Lane from times to times, there is always something in it that we thought was not there.

Personally, I learned a lot from *[Sheaves in geometry and logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0927-0)* when I had only a basic categorical luggage. It is very readable, it is quasi self contained (especially every basic notion is recalled as some point) and it goes quite far inside topos theory.

Some of the books I cited before have a free preprint (or final) version. The other are famous enough that you can find a way to have a look at them...

Comment: There are also these books aimed at certain applications:

Category Theory for the Sciences, by David Spivak. https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/category-theory-sciences

Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists, by Benjamin Pierce. https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/basic-category-theory-computer-scientists

Category Theory for Computing Science by Michael Barr and Charles Wells. http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/22/tr22.pdf

Comment: @SixWingedSeraph Thanks for these addings, I didn't thought about the more applied stuff.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Remark I put Lurie in "higher category theory", not in "homotopy theory" (I assume people goes through some homotopical algebra before higher stuff in general but I might be wrong). That being said, the first chapters of HTT are not that hard to read iirc, Lurie makes a pretty good job conveying intuitions. And HTT's appendices are a gold mine of _usual_ results in homotopical algebra. (Of course, it is also a matter of taste.)

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other suggestions: I think Riehl's second book, Categorical Homotopy Theory, is the best manageable introduction to higher category theory and homotopical algebra. It also contains a brief introduction on enriched category theory, but you should really read Kelly's book on the latter subject.

2-category theory (and low dimensional category theory in general) is an important area lacking a monograph, but Steve Lack's "A 2-Categories Companion" was designed to approximate this role: it's more a guide to the literature in an area which I'd argue is in the middle of a second flowering.

Finally, Borceux had a three-volume magnum opus surveying all of category theory at the time of writing, which may be the best way to get an idea of what all is a part of the field.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know more specifically what you have in mind when you speak of "a second flowering".

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Well, you would know better than me, and I'm perfectly prepared to be entirely off base about this, but I was thinking of work like https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3191, https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2111, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607646, and http://comp.mq.edu.au/~rgarner/Papers/CT07.pdf, which it seems to me picks up after a bit of a slowdown ca. 1985-2000.

Comment: I should also mention the program of Riehl and Verity to base $\infty$-category theory on 2-category theory as a very notable area of application.